# How to calculate the size of cell in UITableView when using grouped style?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm working on a universal app and the view I'm working on is common to iPhone and iPad.
I display a UITableView (with grouped style) and I made a custom cell (programmatically - no nib). I read somewhere (can't find where anymore) that the margins are of 1/16 * width of the table. So I set the width of my custom cell to 14/16 * width of the table but that's not good. Or at least it doesn't work well.

Can someone confirm or invalidate that the margins are 1/16 * width of the table?

And in the case that's not 1/16, how can compute that size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone portrait margins : 10 pixels
iPhone landscape or iPad margins: 
  - if table width<400 then 10 pixels
  - else margin = 6% of table width, with minimum of 31 pixels, max of 45 pixels

Comment: source? isn't there anything built-in the SDK to have those sizes ?

Comment: what about the iphone in landscape orientation? 10px as well ?

Comment: Let me edit this, if iPhone landscape with tableView width>400, then behaves like iPad

Comment: I am not sure where I got that from, I have been using this for a while in my code

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default horizontal margin is 10 pixels. But you could use auto resizing, eg UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth. Look at the UIView documentation.